# Create a new VM

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a server app01t for testing proposal on hvserver01. We want to create a new one for same proposals. I already do export from app01t01, on hvserver01, copy the files to hvserver 02 and do import into Hyper-V. But I have to change IP address and the name to app02t.

Is this the best way? Or do export from server, copy the VHDs to other server and make a new machine with bases of the export VHDs? Or perhaps do a clone?

Comment: Please try to make the question more readable. Please put the actual questions in a new paragraph and state what is your operating system and more details about your situation.

Comment: Is your specific question the best way to create an exact copy of an existing VM changing only the IP address and the DNS name so the new server can coexist with the old on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

The *cleanest* way I know is:

1. Shut down the virtual 'donor machine' and make a backup of it. You will need it!
   The very original one. `app01t01` in this case.
2. Boot the machine as you would normally, then [generalize your installation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824938.aspx).
3. The machine will shut down by itself.
4. Make a copy of the machine now, as many as you want. Once these copies boot - anywhere - they will be like brand new machines, guiding you through the basic setup. Don't worry, your files are all there, but this is how you copy a Windows install clean and proper.
5. Now you can move back the backup you made of `app01t01`, so it will boot just as before.

This is how I have always done it.